# How to insert fields into a link field in twig?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

We have several fields on our `Article` content type, one of which is a `Link` field. In a `twig` template we would like to display a `<section>` such that all of it is clickable with different fields inside of it.

Current `node--article.html.twig`

```
<section>
  <a href={{ url }}>{{ label }}</a>
  <div>{{ content.body }}</div>
  <div>{{ content.field_subtitle }}</div>
  <div>{{ content.field_category }}</div>
</section>
```

Modified `node--article.html.twig` template to make entire `<section>` clickable (desired output).

```
<a href={{ url }} >
  <div>{{ content.body }}</div>
  <div>{{ content.field_subtitle }}</div>
  <div>{{ content.field_category }}</div>
</a>
```

**Is there another way I should be doing this?**

I was looking for something similar to below. It would output what is under the `Modified node--article.html.twig` (above)

```
{{ link(label, url)|insert(content.body, content.field_subtitle, content.field_category) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything for the `insert` tag in Twig or Drupal, but you can preprocess the `url` variable in `mytheme.theme` and pass it to the template, giving you what you want:

```
<a href="{{ url }}" >
  <div>{{ content.body }}</div>
  <div>{{ content.field_subtitle }}</div>
  <div>{{ content.field_category }}</div>
</a>
```

The `url` variable would be created in the preprocess function.

If its a standard link field, you could try:

```
$link = $node->get('field_link')->getValue();

if (!$external) {
  $variables['url'] = Url::fromUri($link['uri'])->toString();
}
else {
  $variables['url'] = $link['uri'];
}
```

Edit: totally forgot the line that checks if it is external.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `{{ node.field_link.0['#url'] }}` to get the absolute value of a url in a link field.

You can use `{{ dump(_context) }}` temporarily to get exact array key names and values out of twig debug.